# Is that possible to develop one application in both WPF and Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, macos, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, multiplatform

I've already worked with `WPF` but i don't know anything about `SilverLight`now I need to develop an application which can run on both Mac and Windows,so i was thinking to write an `WPF Application` with `MVVM` for `Windows` and run it on Mac Using `SilverLight`?Is that possible to port from `WPF` to `Silverlight` and how much work needs or maybe should I write the application with `SilverLight` from beginning,even for my `Windows` users?Which one is better and faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a quick answer is Yes..

but lot of things to do. You could share **most of** XAML view across platform but not all of them.

1. try to put all business logic into service layer like BAL or middle tier
2. put presentation logic into ViewModel class library
3. create separate XAML View (for SL and WPF)

there are several docs about target multi-platform here..

- [A Cross-platform WPF, Silverlight & WP7 Application at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254506/XAMLFinance-A-Cross-platform-WPF-Silverlight-WP7-A)
- [Sharing Code Between Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921109%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)